# Ensuring Type Safety with Dynamic Key-Function Mapping in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm working with TypeScript and facing a challenge related to ensuring type safety when dynamically mapping keys to specific processing functions. Below is the TypeScript code snippet that illustrates my issue:

```
interface Foo {
  foo: string
}

interface Bar {
  bar: string
}

const fooProcessor = (foo: Foo) => {
  return foo
}

const barProcessor = (bar: Bar) => {
  return bar
}

const processorMap = {
  foo: fooProcessor,
  bar: barProcessor,
}

const fooGenerator = () => ({ foo: '123' } as Foo)
const barGenerator = () => ({ bar: '123' } as Bar)

const generatorMap = {
  foo: fooGenerator,
  bar: barGenerator,
}

const topLevelProcessor = (type: 'foo' | 'bar') => {
  const object = generatorMap[type]()

  return processorMap[type](object)
}
```

The challenge is in the `topLevelProcessor` function, where TypeScript is unable to infer the correct type for object and the function `processorMap[type]`. This results in a type mismatch error. I'm trying to avoid using as any to maintain strong type safety.

Comment: You must establish a binding between string literal(s) `'foo'` and corresponding type(s) `Foo`. Typescript fails to infer type based on string literal because it has no knowledge those match each other.

Comment: @VasilyLiaskovsky How do I do that?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WJB7ZW) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @wonderflame Yes it does and it seems to be much simpler than VasilyLiaskovsky's approach.

Comment: Okay, will write an answer soon

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way to establish binding between string literals and types is to create auxiliary interface (`KnownTypeBinding` below):

```
interface Foo {
  foo: string;
}

interface Bar {
  bar: string;
}

interface KnownTypeBinding {
  foo: Foo;
  bar: Bar;
}

type KnownTypeName = keyof KnownTypeBinding;
type KnownType = KnownTypeBinding[KnownTypeName];

type TypeProcessor<T extends KnownType> = (x: T) => T;
type TypeGenerator<T extends KnownType> = () => T;

type ProcessorMap = {
  [K in KnownTypeName]: TypeProcessor<KnownTypeBinding[K]>;
}

const processorMap: ProcessorMap = {
  foo: (foo: Foo) => { return foo; },
  bar: (bar: Bar) => { return bar; }
}

type GeneratorMap = {
  [K in KnownTypeName]: TypeGenerator<KnownTypeBinding[K]>;
}

const generatorMap: GeneratorMap = {
  foo: () => { return { foo: 'foo' }; },
  bar: () => { return { bar: 'bar' }; }
}

type TopLevelProcessor = <K extends KnownTypeName>(type: K) => KnownTypeBinding[K];

const topLevelProcessor: TopLevelProcessor = <K extends KnownTypeName>(type: K) => {
  const object = generatorMap[type]()
  return processorMap[type](object);
}
```